# Retrofit parameter going null on server side in galaxy j7 phone android

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, samsung-mobile

Am trying to upload multiple  parameter  in retrofit it's working Fine in emulator and Other Phone But When I try same code in Samsung phone it's  parameters receive null in php service 
my code is:-

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("add_restaurant.php")
Call<Res_general_bean> res_infodata(@FieldMap HashMap<String,String> data);
```

my web service is:-

```
    private void resInfoUpload() {
  //  progress_dailog .dialog_show();
    HashMap <String,String> userHash = new HashMap<>();

    userHash.put("vender_id",venderid);
    userHash.put("name", srestronant_name);
    userHash.put("description", srestornant_description);
    userHash.put("service_postal_code", srestronant_postalcode);
    userHash.put("service_category", srestronant_category);
    userHash.put("location", slocation);
    userHash.put("street", sstreet_line);
    userHash.put("city", scity);
    userHash.put("state", sstate);
    userHash.put("country", sres_country);
    userHash.put("restaurant_postal_code", spostal_code);
    userHash.put("logo", logo);
    userHash.put("res_images", photo);
    userHash.put("lat", sLat);
    userHash.put("lng", sLng);

    TestForDATA.setUserHash(userHash);
    Retrofit retrofit;


    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Url_path.baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();


    RegisterAPI service = retrofit.create(RegisterAPI.class);

    Call<Res_general_bean> call = service.res_infodata(userHash);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Res_general_bean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Res_general_bean> call, Response<Res_general_bean> response) {
            Log.d("keyR",response.body().getStatus());
            String statusResponse = response.body().getStatus();
            DataRes user = null;
            if (statusResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {//not run single time
                 user=response.body().getData();
                Log.d("keyR",response.body().getData().getRestaurant_id());


            }else {//statusResponse =false  Somtime run hare
                Snackbar_Show.showMsg(Res_photo_logo.this,findViewById(R.id.lay),response.body().getData().getValue()+"");

            }
            progress_dailog .dialog_dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Res_general_bean> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("keyR","failed");
            progress_dailog .dialog_dismiss();
        }
    });

    Log.d("heee", userHash.size()+"");
}
```

some time onResponse() working but web service response false Null value receive and some time it's going onFailure .

```
userHash.put("logo", logo);  /*it's contents single image encode as String*/ 
userHash.put("res_images", photo);/*it's contents 5 images encode as String With Comma */
```

this two parameter hash larger String

Comment: Check with log before sending values to parameters before calling your api's.To be precise print a log of all parameters before and after getting image your logo and photo

Comment: i checked in debugger All value fill

Comment: This code work in other phone

Comment: During image capture or any other intent calling other activity there will be orientation change in some devices(samasung) and works well in other devices

Comment: so better use onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState for all parameter data.

Comment: i am getting value in debugger